# random generator returning multiple results

Tags: java, random

The code reads from text file and goes true all 1000 words in txt. It then read each word calculate ist lenght and from that lenght gets random number (say lenght is 4 and random would be 2). It then replaces that random numbers character with "*". This would be later used as an sample into main program.

Problem is at the moment i am getting same as an result multiple times.

TXT:

http://textuploader.com/oyfi

```
public class random_2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int dolzina = 0;
Object s;
    String outputFile = "random_2.txt";
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();

    try {

        File file = new File("random1.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String vrstica;
        while ((vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            list.add(vrstica);
            // dolzina=list.size();
            // System.out.println(dolzina);

        }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
        for (int idx = 0; idx <= list.size(); ++idx) {
            String test=list.get(idx);
            dolzina=test.length();
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i<= dolzina; ++i) {
                int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(dolzina);
                StringBuilder beseda = new StringBuilder(test);
                beseda.setCharAt(randomInt, '*');
                System.out.println(beseda);

        }
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the constructor

```
Random(long seed)
```

A random generator can be view as an object that have a predefined list number, and returning at each call the next number into the list.

Using the Random(long seed) will give the first index to start with into the list.

Here into your code, you always start the random list at position 0.

Concretely, we use for the 'seed' parameter the actual time in millisecond. So each time you run your program, you will initalize the random generator with a different start index, and you will get a different result each run time.

Comment: this program would only be runned once! and words would be saved to  a new txt file, which would later be used. Start index should be 0 so i can chech the whole list?